# Custom number format with empty parts?

Tags: excel

I want to use standard duration fields.

```
5h23m12s
5m22s
10s
```

It seems like the format could be supported using string literals.

```
h"h"m"m"s"s"
```

It works with zero values using the following pattern.

```
0h0m12s    <- works
12s        <- doesn't work
```

How can I make the hours and minutes optional?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this custom number format:

```
[>=0.0416666666]h\hm\ms\s;[>=0.000694444]m\ms\s;s\s
```

Remember, you will still need to <kbd>ENTER</kbd> the times correctly

[image]